# Convert mixed nested list (mixed tuples and lists of 2 dimension) to 1 dim list

Tags: python-2.7, list, nested, converters

I've got a mixed list, containing lists with tuples (2nd dimension), looking like this:

```
[[(0, 500), (755, 1800)], [2600, 2900], [4900, 9000], [(11000, 17200)]]
```

The list should look like this

```
[[0, 500], [755, 1800], [2600, 2900], [4900, 9000], [11000, 17200]]
```

I tried it with map and the call to the list() convert function.

```
#Try 1: works for just the first element
experiment = map(list,cleanedSeg[0])
#Try 2: gives error int not interabel
experiment = [map(list,elem) for elem in cleanedSeg if isinstance(elem, (tuple, list))]
#Try 3: 
experiment = [list(x for x in xs) for xs in cleanedSeg]

print experiment
```

none of them did solve my issue

Comment: is it possible to have nested lists with greater level like `[[[(0, 500)], [[(456, 90), [56, 85]]]]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mixlist = [[(0, 500), (755, 1800)], [2600, 2900], [4900, 9000], [(11000, 17200)]]

# [[0, 500], [755, 1800], [2600, 2900], [4900, 9000], [11000, 17200]]
experiment = [list(n) if isinstance(n, tuple) else [n] for sub in mixlist for n in sub]
```

I tried two version of the list comprehension below. The above one and another alternative where

```
experiment = [list(n) if isinstance(n, tuple) else list(n) for sub in mixlist for n in sub]
```

This expression gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument of type 'int' is not iterable.
```

The difference between these two expressions is using list literal, [] and list function, ().

```
list_literal = [n] # Gives a list literal [n]
ls = list(n) # Iterate over n's items and produce a list from that.
```

For example:

```
>>> n = (1,2,3)
>>> list_literal = [n]
>>> list_literal
[(1, 2, 3)]
>>> n = (1,2,3)
>>> list_literal = list(n)
>>> list_literal
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I meanwhile found a workaround, in which I edited the function which gave me the list. I changed it so that I only get lists (no more tuples) which I then flattened. However the output for your post looks like this [[0, 500], [755, 1800], [2600], [2900], [4900], [9000], [11000, 17200]]. So that [2600,2900] is not paired as well as [4900,9000].

Comment: I see. Please note that using list comprehension is better, in terms of speed and memory. I'm glad you found a workaround though!